# req.body comes empty or partially empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have been playing around with node js. I was following a tutorial and as the tutorial was old I had to tweak few stuffs but now I am totally at the dead end and as my final hope, I am coming to stackoverflow.

I am creating a restful routes for a simple to-do app.(just learning)

Below is my model.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var Task = new mongoose.Schema({
    taskTitle:{
      type:String,
      default:"",
      required:true
    },
    taskDescription:{
      type:String,
      default:"",
      required:true
    },
    taskStartDate:{
      type:Number,
      required:true
    },
    taskEndDate:{
      type:Number,
      required:true
    },
    userId:{
      type:Number,
      required:true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Task",Task);
```

Here's my route to add a task:  this is in `./controllers/task.js` file

```
exports.addTask = function(req, res){

  var task = new Task();

  task.taskTitle = req.body.taskTitle;
  task.taskDescription = req.body.desc;
  task.taskStartDate = req.body.startDate;
  task.taskEndDate = req.body.endDate;
  task.userId = req.body.userId;

  task.save(function(err){
         if(err){
           console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))
           res.send("There is an error")
         }
         else{
           res.send({message:"task was saved.",data:task});
       }
  });
};
```

My `server.js` looks simple.

```
var express = require("express");
var taskController = require("./controllers/tasks");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/tasker');


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended:true

}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api',router);




router.route("/tasks/:userId").get(taskController.getTasks);
router.route("/task").get(taskController.getTask);
router.route("/addTask").post(taskController.addTask);
router.route("/updateTask").post(taskController.updateTask);
router.route("/deleteTask").get(taskController.deleteTask);

app.listen(3000);
```

SO my problem is when I do postman request my `req.body` just contains

```
{"startDate":"10102015","endDate":"10102018"}
```

my `req.body` doesn't have no `desc`, `taskTitle`, and `userID`. 
I have been trying for hours and don't know what's the error here.

[image: My postman request looks like this:]

Thanks a lot

Comment: The request body is expecting data as JSON body. Post your request as raw -> JSON on postman.

Comment: @Olantobi: There’s a `bodyParser.urlencoded` though?

Comment: I tried with your code and it worked fine for me. I received all the fields.

Comment: it worked for me now. I did not change anything.